# Prove that $fg\in L^r(\Omega)$ if $f\in L^p(\Omega),g\in L^q(\Omega)$, and $\frac1 p+\frac1 q=\frac1 r$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Can anyone give me a hint for proving the following:

Let $\Omega$ be a measure space. Assume $f \in L^p(\Omega)$ and $g \in L^q(\Omega)$ with $1 \leq p, q \leq \infty$ and $\frac1p + \frac1q \leq 1$. Prove that $fg \in L^r(\Omega)$ with $\frac1r = \frac1p + \frac1q$.

Note: One should be able to use (the standard) Hölder inequality. Notice that if you have $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$ you recover the former result.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hint:
$$
1 = \frac{r}{p}+\frac{r}{q} = \frac{1}{\frac{p}{r}}+\frac{1}{\frac{q}{r}}
$$

Answer (score 21):

Using the standard Hölder inequality:
$$
\|fg\|_r^r=\|f^rg^r\|_1\le\|f^r\|_{p/r}\|g^r\|_{q/r}=\|f\|_p^r\|g\|_q^r
$$
Since $\frac{r}{p}+\frac{r}{q}=1$.

Answer (score 4):

we can  remark  that  : $$\frac 1{p'} +  \frac 1{q'} = 1$$   where : $$p'=\frac pr ;  q'=\frac qr$$
and proof  that  $f^r \in L^{p'}$  and  $g^r \in L^{q'}$

Comment: You must mean $q'=q/r$.