# is $\|\cdot\|_p\leq \|\cdot\|_{p'}$ for $p<p'$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Consider the $L^p$ spaces.
is $\|\cdot\|_p\leq \|\cdot\|_{p'}$ for $p<p'$?
is it true if the domain of $L^p$ is finite measure?

Thanks

Comment: no, one has a constant that is not equal to 1 (in general). but it is true if the domain has finite measure

Comment: So there is $C>0$ such that $\|\cdot\|_p\leq\|\cdot\|_{p'}$? Is it true generally or only in finite measure? also, why is it true generally?

Comment: in the answer I'll just post the correct result

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! To attract answers to your question, please add some context and background information. For example, where did you encounter this problem (e.g. a book, class, real-life)? Please also show your attempt; seeing your work helps us help you. If this is homework, please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353).

Answer (score 1):

If $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ then it follows from Hölder's inequality that $||f||_{L^p} \leq C||f||_{L^{p'}}$ whenever $f\in L^{p'}$, where $C$ depends only on $\mu(\Omega)$, $p$, and $p'$. The result is false if the measure is not finite: consider $\mathbf{R}$, it is easy to find an $L^2(\mathbf{R})$ function that does not lie in $L^1(\mathbf{R})$.

Comment: Thanks. Why does it follows from Holder's? isn't holder only relevant for $1/p+1/q=1$? and every then, it only gives estimation of $\|\cdot\|_1$

Comment: @JackTheRunner: there is a more general version of Hölder which is used to prove this. It says if $1/p+1/q\leqslant 1$ and $1/r=1/p+1/q$ and $f\in L^p$, $g\in L^q$ then $fg\in L^r$.

Comment: Could you please link me to it? Can't seem to find it on the internet

Comment: @JackTheRunner: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159887/generalized-h%C3%B6lder-inequality

Comment: Thanks. one last question - is there a closed form of a possible $C$ in terms of $\mu(\Omega),p,p'$? Is there anything special that can't be said if $\mu$ is a probability measure?

Comment: @JackTheRunner: try to prove it using that inequality and you'll get the $C$!