# Doubt in variant of Holder inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, holder-inequality

Let $p, q, r \in [1, \infty), r \neq \infty$ such that $1/p+1/q=1/r$.
If  $f \in {L(X)} ^ p$ and $g \in {L (X)}^q$. Is it true that $|f|^{p/r}<|f|^p$? According to I do not, because if I consider $f = 1/2$ constant and $p = 4 = q$ and $r = 2$ all in space $X = [0,1]$ then $ \int |f|^4 <\infty$ but $|1/2|^2 <|1/2|^ {4}$ something absurd. It is right?

Comment: What you have done is right but you are very likely to have copied the statement wrongly from somewhere. You can never expect an inequality for powers of the function from integrability. The inequality probably  was stated for some norms of $f$ in $L^{p}$ and $L^{q}$.

Comment: Exactly the problem is:
$p,q,r\in [1,\infty] with r\neq \infty$ such that $1/p+1/q=1/r$. If $f\in L^p$ and $g\in L^q$ then $|fg|_{r}\leq |f|_p|g|_q$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159887/generalized-h%C3%B6lder-inequality

Comment: Thanks but I already solved the problem. My question is the question on the subject.